# Cursor do not follow the position of drawn rectangle in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have this code that let me draw rectangle on canvas:
https://jsfiddle.net/6u7bLkwc/4/

In order to draw a rectangle on the canvas, click on the image and then drag your mouse.

**To reproduce my problem please follow this steps:**

- Draw a rectangle like mentionned in the top.
- And then click on ADD TEXT button.
- Now try to draw another rectangle, you will see that your cursor are not in the same way with the rectangle.

How to make my code work even if i add or remove any elements on the page dynamically?

**I tried to do like this:**

```
var shape = new Shape(mouseDownX - canvasOffset.left, mouseDownY - canvasOffset.top, mouseX - mouseDownX, mouseY - mouseDownY, color);
```

But didn't resolved it.

Something like updating new positions will solve it, but not have idea about how to process.

Comment: Check the solution below :)

Comment: This not solved the problem totally, please look here about the same script but still the problem there: jsfiddle.net/dkboaq7p/1

Comment: check again the first and second example you have provided are different cases

Comment: @YehiaAwad check the last case, is what i am looking for to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the solution over here : https://jsfiddle.net/6u7bLkwc/9/

the problem is that you are not calculating the PageX and PageY relative to the canvas position, but instead to the whole page which is giving you wrong coordinates.

I have just changed these:

```
mouseDownX = e.pageX;
mouseDownY = e.pageY;
```

to this:

```
mouseDownX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
mouseDownY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
```

**UPDATE**

For some other cases you should just use  getBoundingClientRect() method  on the canvas to get  the element position relative to the viewport as the following jsfiddle shows sfiddle.net/dkboaq7p/2

// Get Element's relative position

```
var canvasPosition=document.getElementById("canvas").getBoundingClientRect();

  mouseDownX =  e.pageX - canvasPosition.left;
  mouseDownY =  e.pageY - canvasPosition.top;
```

Comment: This not solved the problem totally, please look here about the same script but still the problem there: https://jsfiddle.net/dkboaq7p/1/

Comment: @JisMaxi https://jsfiddle.net/dkboaq7p/2/ << check this for this other case you can use getBoundingClientRect() method to get the element position relative to the page

Comment: please take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/dkboaq7p/3/, add a rectangle, and then click on `HIDE TEXT`, try again to add rectangle you will see the problem again. Try to solve this last one ... the solution i think like i wrote it in the post, must get the new offsets after hidding `#thediv` (Look in this way).

Comment: You should use getBoundingClientRect together with e.clientX/Y. Both refer to *viewport* coordinates then. Don't mix page coordinates with viewport coordinates..